# During gerrit push getting error like (no new changes)

Tags: git, gitlab, gerrit

I have a situation where I hard reset from one branch to another.After reseting while i was trying to push, I am getting the following error.

```
 $ git push http://obulis@192.168.15.19:8088/dummy/dummy-services   HEAD:refs/for/master
 Password for 'http://obulis@192.168.15.19:8088':
 Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
 remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
 To http://obulis@192.168.15.19:8088/dummy/dummy-services
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (no new changes)
 error: failed to push some refs to    'http://obulis@192.168.15.19:8088/dummy/dummy-services'
```

Comment: You try to push nothing. You need a new commit to push

Comment: bu the the hard rested branch have 21 commits.you are saying like i need to add a dummy commit ?

Comment: Gerrit is ahead of your local repo in terms of commit. You can reset the branch locally but gerrit will not see that as new commit. Adding a dummy commit will not help because them the branches will have diverted

Comment: Oh ok. so what will be the solution for this issue?

Comment: force push while circumventing gerrit, or revert your local repo to a previous state instead of hard resetting, and commit the revert

Comment: I think if you update your remote branch with existing commits it is no sense to push them into review branch. Instead of you should push them directly with force push permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gerrit will not accept pushes for a commit that already exists in its underlying git repository (If my memory serves me right even if you are trying to push for a branch that does not yet have that commit). It insists on getting a new commit into its git repo.

You need to make sure that the commit you try to push has a new commit id. This can be achieved e.g. by rewriting the commit message in some trivial way using e.g. commit --amend.